# MySQL - Group By, Max, Inner Join - issue

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, aggregate-functions

Having trouble with a SQL in MySQL. Not sure the correct was to bring back all of the **Awards** my **Users** have won... but only the highest **AwardLevel** of the **Award** they have won. The relation ship is as follows:

A **User** can win many **AwardLevel(s)**. Each **AwardLevel** is tied to a category called an **Award**. **AwardLevels** have a difficulty rating (1, 2, or 3)
This is similar to Stackoverflow's Badges and passing through a Bronze, Silver and Gold type of the Award.

I'm trying to bring back all the Awards for a User but filtered to the Max(difficulty) rating. For example, for a user to get to Level 3 (difficulty = 3) they must first earn the difficulty = 1 and then difficulty = 2. I don't want to show all three levels with my query just the highest (MAX). The problem with my current query is the GROUP BY seems to grab the first record it finds for the Award. Which sometimes is not the one with the difficulty = 3. Not sure if I should be putting the MAX expression somewhere else in the query.

**UPDATED QUERY**:

```
SELECT a.*, MAX(awlev.difficulty)
FROM Award AS a
    INNER JOIN AwardLevel AS awlev ON awlev.id = a.level_id
WHERE a.user_id = 3 -- just a sample user_id
GROUP BY awlev.category_id
```

**TABLE SETUP**:
-- Note: I had forgotten the table relating Users 
-- to won AwardLevels in this table setup I call it UserAwardLevels

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     fullname VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE AwardLevels (
     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     levelname VARCHAR(100),
     difficulty INT
);

CREATE TABLE Awards (
     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     awardname VARCHAR(100)         
);

CREATE TABLE UserAwardLevels (
  user_id INT,
  awardlevel_id INT
);

CREATE TABLE AwardLevels (
     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     levelname VARCHAR(100),
     difficulty INT
);
```

Comment: Can a user win multiple awards with the same award level?

Comment: In your query there is no table with a alias of `t`. Please fix.

Comment: didn't really understand your structure. what's t in t.user_id? can you post the structure of the table?

Comment: corrected the issue. I was trying to simplify problem. Boil it down to the major issue. Query corrected. the user_id field is part of the Award records.

Comment: @The Scrum Meister, You can only win 1 Level 1 time. You can win level 1, level 2, and level 3 within a category (which is Award).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want, in Mysql it is a little clumsy because windowing functions are not available. However, you can try

```
SELECT a.* /* put desired columns in */
FROM AwardLevel as awlev JOIN Award AS a
ON awlev2.id = a2.level_id
JOIN
  SELECT (a2.user_id, MAX(awlev2.difficulty) AS maxdifficulty
     FROM Award AS a2 INNER JOIN AwardLevel2 AS awlev2 ON awlev2.id = a2.level_id
     GROUP BY a2.user_id, awlev2.category_id) AS subquery
ON a.user_id = subquery.user_id AND awlev.difficulty = maxdifficulty
WHERE a.user_id = 999; /* whatever id */
```

The optimizer will probably improve this, and I am not sure if the join of `awlev` and `a` is necessary without seeing the schema.